# Should I store totals in a database to count likes and comments instead of doing a SELECT count() every time someone visits a page?

Tags: php, sql

I am playing around with PHP and SQl. Currently I am building a test page that contains the earth's fauna. Right now I will only focus on trees and flowers. When someone first visits the page, they will see a list like this.

- Trees

  - Pine      Likes 10  Comments 11
  - Oak       Likes 20  Comments 2
  - Cedar     Likes 7   Comments 1
- Flowers

  - Rose     Likes 209 Comments 4
  - Orchid   Likes 550 Comments 193

In order for me to count the likes I go through every single tree and flower type then do a count for each of their comments and likes. Since this is fairly new, this doesn't take a long time. What scares me is that what would happen if this becomes bigger. I am aware that `SELECT COUNT(id)` is fast, but when you do it on multiple records it can slow down a page.

Now, my question, is: Should I instead create another table called totals, and store the total comments and likes of an item. With the new table when someone creates a comment or like, or unlikes and deletes comment, I could add or subtract from the totals.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit baffled as to how your data model supports the summary that you have suggested.  Sample data in addition to desired results helps.  A db<>fiddle or SQL fiddle can help.

Comment: Storing count could become its own nightmare where deletions are concerned. Nice graph by the way. Superb.

Comment: Computing `COUNT` with the right indexes is likely to be cheaper than constantly updating the `totals` table using triggers.